# Java Map to reject put if value differs

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a nice implementation of a `Map`, or method on a map, which will reject (with an exception) a `put` if the entry already exists and the value being put differs from the value already in the map?

Here is some code illustrating what I would like

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); // Could be a different Map impl

// Init the map with some entries
map.put("key", "value");
map.put("anotherKey", "anotherValue");
        
map.put("key", "value"); // No issue as the value matches the existing
map.put("key", "differentValue"); // This should throw as we are attempting to change the value
```

So it would be a type of map with immutable entries once added. The JavaDoc on Map.put suggest this can fit within the Map contract

```
* @throws IllegalArgumentException if some property of the specified key
*         or value prevents it from being stored in this map
```

I can write code to do this but felt like there might already be a great solution i'm not aware of?

Comment: Can't you work with `.contains(key)` for this?

Comment: `putIfAbsent` (in `ConcurrentMap`) will put the value only if it is new. If not, it won't do anything (if it was the value was same, you don't need anything done anyway, if it was different you want it rejected).

Comment: If you use the same key, then the previous value of this key will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `containsKey` and `get` functions to compare the key and value existence as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); 

    map.put("key", "value");
    try {
         addToMap(map, "key", "value");
         addToMap(map, "anotherKey", "anotherValue");
            
         addToMap(map, "key", "value");
         addToMap(map, "key", "differentValue");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
private static void addToMap(Map<String, String> map, String key, String value) throws Exception {
    if(map.containsKey(key) && !map.get(key).equals(value))
        throw new Exception("exception");
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.Exception: exception
    at Main.addToMap(Main.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
{anotherKey=anotherValue, key=value}
```